# Node.js wait until one async task succeeds

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

How can I spawn some tasks and stop executing when one task does not give an error? I wrote some code that does this, but in my opinion, the code is not very readable. Is there a pattern or a best practice how this can be done?

The code bellow will try to find an available folder and stops searching when a folder is found. This is just some demo code. Error handling is for example missing when no folder is found.

The code:

```
getAvailableSubFolder(callback) {
    var promises = [];

    var folderToUse = null;
    var errorToReturn = null;

    var self = this;
    for (let folderName = 0; folderName < config.storage.maxSubFolders; folderName++) {
      promises.push(new Promise(function (finished) {
        let folder = config.storage.fileLocation + folderName;
        self._spaceInFolder(folder, (error, space) => {
          if (folderToUse !== null || errorToReturn !== null) {
            finished();
            return;
          }

          if (error !== null || space) {
            folderToUse = space ? folder : null;
            errorToReturn = error;
            finished();
            return;
          }

          finished();
        });
      }));
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
      callback(errorToReturn, folderToUse);
    });
  }
```